# Story of a nation where a wall divides the sexes

Tags: story-identification

What novel is this?

The band of adventurers first see a low wall, easy to step over. It grows taller as it approaches the kingdom, with illustrations indicating *boys on this side; girls on that side*.  Finally in the kingdom it is a formitable barrier and the society is very strict.

Of course, the government rulers cross freely via hidden tunnels and don’t practice the culture they preach.

I think this was the same story: the people keep in touch with communicators hidden in fake fingernails. The holographic circuitry allows it to be trimmed to fit. To use, the wearer sticks one finger in his ear and talks into another.

I'm thinking that would be Harry Harrison.

Anyone remember it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is "[The Stainless Steel Rat Sings the Blues](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441881581)" by Harry Harrison.

- ***Gender-segregated wall***

  > The brick wall was as high as our waists now; Floyd put one hand on it and vaulted over, bent and looked.
  >   "Maybe, but not too clear. Could have been here once but it is so overgrown with grass that it is hard to tell. Can I come back now?"
  >   "Yes—because it's about time for a decision." I pointed ahead to the slowly heightening wall. "The Fundamentaloids said they came to the city to trade. So they must have come this way, possibly made this track that we are following."
  >   Madonette nodded agreement—and didn't like it. "And they were all men, I remember that all too clearly. Unclean indeed! No women allowed. Or if the women did come this way they would have to have walked over on the other side of the wall. What do you want us to do, Jim?"
  >   "What do we want to do? As I said—it's time for a decision. Do we all stick together and ignore the obvious instructions? That's the first question that we have to answer."
  >   "Do that and I'll bet that eventually we get into some kind of trouble," she said. "A lot of serious work went into this wall. So if we don't read the message something not too nice is guaranteed to happen. It always does on this world. The choice is mine. I'll cross over and trot down the other side—"
- **Talking into fingernails**

  > "Of course it does," Tremeame said, speaking through my fingernail instead of my jaw for a change.
  >   While we had been installing the MIPSCS we had been going over and over all of the possibilities, had returned always to the only viable plan.
  >   "Let's do it," Madonette said, admiring her new communicating fingernails. She put on her pack, shrugged it into comfortable position, then turned and walked off on her side of the barrier. With each step the wall grew higher, until, very quickly, it was as high as her head, then higher. After a last wave of her hand she vanished from sight.
  >   "Keep in touch," I said into my pinkie. "Regular reports and sing out if you see anything—anything at all."
  >   " Just as you say, boss."

[image]